# How to train custom object detection with tfrecord file

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, object-detection, tfrecord, roboflow

here I want to train a object detection model, so I have annotated the data using roboflow and then exported it as tfrecords and also got the (.pbtxt file) and after that I don't have any clue  on how to train a can model from scratch with just 2,3 number of hidden layers. am not getting on how to use that tfrecord to fit in my model which I have created. please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tfrecord` files are usually used with Tensorflow Object Detection. It's pretty old and I haven't seen it used in practice recently, but there's [a Tensorflow Object Detection tutorial here](https://blog.roboflow.com/how-to-train-a-tensorflow-lite-object-detection-model/) that uses these `tfrecord` files.

If there's not a particular reason you need to use TF Object Detection I'd recommend using a newer and more well-supported model like [YOLOv5](https://blog.roboflow.com/how-to-train-yolov5-on-a-custom-dataset/) or [YOLOv7](https://blog.roboflow.com/yolov7-custom-dataset-training-tutorial/).